# Is it possible to create a form to send information from the site to a WhatsApp or Telegram number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, telegram, telegram-bot

sorry for the long introduction
I have a form on my website to submit the information customers enter to the Telegram bot

no matter what I do, someone is hacking into my bot and getting this information
I changed the bot multiple times and obfuscate the javascript and it's still the same

Is there any way to change the sending of information from the bot to my phone number on Telegram instead or any way to hide the bot token so they can't get it

shortly my code is:

```
var o = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  telegram_bot_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
o.open(
  "POST",
  "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + telegram_bot_token + "/sendMessage"
),
  o.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"),
  o.send(formdata);
```

Comment: You need to send the information to your own server, then send it from there to telegram after validating it.

Comment: i'm using Blogger for this site ,don't have server and can only use javascrept and he's getting into my bot that's how he know the informations @MosheKatz

Comment: There is no way to make the JavaScript work without also allowing an attacker to take advantage of it. It just cannot be done without a server-side process (either on your own or some kind of hosting service).

Comment: i'll check on this thank you so much for answering @MosheKatz